# Inserting data from one table to another if one field is chosen by user

Tags: sql, ms-access

I searched this website and google for 3-4 hours to see how can I insert two fields of data from one table(such as table1) to another(tests), if one specific data from a column in  tests table **is chosen by user**, then other data from table1 appear on the next column in the tests table.
I used some codes, such as:

```
INSERT INTO Tests SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE PRIMARY_KEY NOT IN 
(SELECT PRIMARY_KEY FROM Tests)
```

(from here:[Update data from one table to another and insert if new ms access .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223266/update-data-from-one-table-to-another-and-insert-if-new-ms-access-net))

```
INSERT INTO Tests(TestMethod, AcceptanceCriteria)
SELECT TestMethod, AcceptanceCriteria 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY TestMethod;
```

(from here: [How to do INSERT into a table records extracted from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162/how-to-do-insert-into-a-table-records-extracted-from-another-table))

```
INSERT INTO Tests ( AcceptanceCriteria1 )
SELECT Table1.AcceptanceCriteria
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.TestMethod) Like ([Tests].[TestMethod] & '*')));
```

(From here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1528492)

But None of them work.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly do you mean by "is chosen by user"? -- Please give a sample of `Table1`, and what you expect to end up in `Test`.

Answer (score -1):

INSERT INTO TABLE2(A,B,C)
SELECT A,B,C 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE C = 1 // here put you condition for specific column  -- e.g